# folder name contain names c# Directory

Tags: c#, regex, directory, filenames

I am working on Excel add-ins with intranet server.

I have names of employees and each one has a folder in the intranet and this folder may has a power point file may not. so I need to read the files for each name.

the Problem is with names: 
each folder name has this Pattern :

> surname, firstname

but the problem is with the names who contain multiple names as a firstname or surname:

> ex:
>   samy jack sammour. 
>   the first name is: "samy jack" and the last name is "sammour"

so the folder would be : sammour, samy jack

but I have only the field name, I don't know what is the last name or the firstname(it could be "jack sammour, samy" or "sammour, samy jack"). so I tried this code to fix it:

```
string[] dirs = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(@"/samy*jack*sammour/","*file*.pptx");
if (dirs.Length > 0)
{
    MessageBox.Show("true");
}
```

but it gave me an error:

> file is not illegal

how can I fix this problem and search all the possibilties

Comment: Best way is to get all files with \*.\* and put into a List<string>.  Then use Linq to do filtering/searching on the List<>.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should do the trick:

```
var path = @"C:\Users\";
var name = "samy jack sammour";

Func<IEnumerable<string>, IEnumerable<string>> permutate = null;
permutate = items =>
    items.Count() > 1 ?
        items.SelectMany(
            (_, ndx1) => permutate(items.Where((__, ndx2) => ndx1 != ndx2)),
            (item1, item2) => item1 + (item2.StartsWith(",") ? "" : " ") + item2) :
        items;

var names = name.Split(new[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Concat(new[] { "," }).ToArray();
var dirs = new HashSet<string>(permutate(names).Where(n => !n.StartsWith(",") && !n.EndsWith(",")), StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
if (new DirectoryInfo(path).EnumerateDirectories().Any(dir => dirs.Contains(dir.Name) && dir.EnumerateFiles("*.pptx").Any()))
    MessageBox.Show("true");
```

In my opinion, you should't do this with a Regex because regexes can't match permutations very well.
Instead you can create a HashSet which contains all case-insensitive permutations that correlate to your pattern:

> surname, firstname

(Case-sensitivity isn't required because the windows file system doesn't care if a directory or file name is upper or lower case.)

For the sake of simplicity I just add the comma to the permutation parts and filter the items that start or end with a comma in a next step.
If performance matters or if the names can consist of many parts I'm sure that there's a way to optimize these possibilities away sooner to prevent large parts of the unnecessary permutations.

In the last step you enumerate the directory names and check if there's a match in this HashSet of all possible names.
When you've found a matching directory you just need to search for all .pptx files in this directory.
If necessary just replace the "*.pptx" with your file name pattern.

Comment: yes but why? While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.